# Angular 10 forkJoin cancelling requests

Tags: angular, rxjs

This should be a simple one for the angular pros out there.
I have this simple method:

```
private addMultiple(products: Product[]): void {
    let observables: Observable<Product>[] = [];

    products.forEach((product: Product) => observables.push(this.productService.create(product)));

    forkJoin(observables).subscribe();
}
```

If I send one product to the method, it works fine, but if I try multiple (100) I just get loads of cancelled requests and I am not sure why.

Does anyone know if I should be using a different method?

---

This is my **productService**:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { finalize, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Product, Attempt, RequestOptions } from '../models';
import { HttpServiceConfig, HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG } from '../configs';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ProductService {
    private endpoint: string = 'products';

    public items: BehaviorSubject<Product[]>;
    public loading: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

    constructor(
        @Inject(HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG) public config: HttpServiceConfig,
        private httpClient: HttpClient
    ) {
        this.items = new BehaviorSubject<Product[]>([]);
        this.loading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    }

    list(categoryId: number, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<Product[]> {
        this.loading.next(true);
        return this.httpClient
        .get<Attempt<Product[]>>(
            `${this.config.apiUrl}/categories/${categoryId}/${this.endpoint}/master`,
            options?.getRequestOptions()
        )
        .pipe(
            map((response: Attempt<Product[]>) => {
            if (response.failure) return response.result;
            this.items.next(response.result);
            return response.result;
            }),
            finalize(() => this.loading.next(false))
        );
    }

    get(id: number, slug: string, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<Product> {
        return this.httpClient
        .get<Attempt<Product>>(
            `${this.config.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}/${id}?slug=${slug}`,
            options?.getRequestOptions()
        )
        .pipe(
            map((response: Attempt<Product>) => {
            return response.result;
            })
        );
    }

    public create(item: Product, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<Product> {
        return this.httpClient
        .post<Attempt<Product>>(
            `${this.config.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}`,
            item,
            options?.getRequestOptions()
        )
        .pipe(
            map((response: Attempt<Product>) => {
            if (response.failure) return response.result;
            const newItem = response.result;
            const items = this.items.value;
            items.push(newItem);
            this.items.next(items);
            return response.result;
            })
        );
    }

    public updateSpecification(
        item: Product,
        options?: RequestOptions
    ): Observable<Product> {
        return this.httpClient
        .put<Attempt<Product>>(
            `${this.config.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}/specification`,
            item,
            options?.getRequestOptions()
        )
        .pipe(
            map((response: Attempt<Product>) => {
            if (response.failure) return response.result;
            const newItem = response.result;
            const items = this.items.value;
            this.remove(items, newItem.id);
            items.push(newItem);
            this.items.next(items);
            return response.result;
            })
        );
    }

    public approve(item: Product, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<Product> {
        return this.httpClient
        .put<Attempt<Product>>(
            `${this.config.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}/approve`,
            item,
            options?.getRequestOptions()
        )
        .pipe(
            map((response: Attempt<Product>) => {
            if (response.failure) return response.result;
            const newItem = response.result;
            const items = this.items.value;
            this.remove(items, newItem.id);
            items.push(newItem);
            this.items.next(items);
            return response.result;
            })
        );
    }

    public reject(item: Product, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<Product> {
        return this.httpClient
        .put<Attempt<Product>>(
            `${this.config.apiUrl}/${this.endpoint}/reject`,
            item,
            options?.getRequestOptions()
        )
        .pipe(
            map((response: Attempt<Product>) => {
            if (response.failure) return response.result;
            const newItem = response.result;
            const items = this.items.value;
            this.remove(items, newItem.id);
            items.push(newItem);
            this.items.next(items);
            return response.result;
            })
        );
    }

    private remove(items: Product[], id: number | string) {
        items.forEach((item, i) => {
        if (item.id !== id) {
            return;
        }
        items.splice(i, 1);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `this.productService.create(product)` return?

Comment: Please include the code for ProductService's create method and what the content of `products` is when you call `addMultiple`

Comment: Possibly, your service on the other side is cancelling the request ? (request throttling or any defence mechanism )

Comment: @ShamPooSham the content of products is from the **list** method on the productService. I add them to a table and then when one or more are selected, they are passed to the method as a new array with the selected products

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be that the server cancels requests if it gets hit by too many requests at almost the same time, which is what happens using `forkJoin` with a hundred of Observables.

`forkJoin` starts the "execution" of all the Observables in parallel.

If you want to control the number of parallel executions, you should try `mergeMap` with the `concurrency`parameter set. This approach can be a bit more complex if you want to match the request with the response.

The code could look something like this

```js
// set the number of requests you want to fly concurrently
const concurrency = 10;
// use from to generate an Observable from an array of Products
from(products).pipe(
  // use mergeMap to execute the request
  mergeMap(product => this.productService.create(product).pipe(
     // return an object which contains the result and the product which started the request
     map(result => ({result, product}))
  ), concurrency),  // set the concurrency in mergeMap
      // toArray transform the stream into an Array if this is what you want
  toArray()
).subscribe(
  res => {// do something with res, which is an array of objects containing objects with result and product}
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I actually don't care about the response, so that should make it much easier

Answer (score 2):

It is important to note that if **any** requests fail during your `create` in a `forkJoin`, remaining requests will be cancelled.

You need to `catchError` on each `create` if you want to make sure all requests don't get cancelled.